# Where is the typescript build option in VS 2019 Community?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio

On VS 2015 when I created a blank node.js web app, if I right click on the project and selected its properties, there was a tab on the left that read "TYPESCRIPT BUILD"

This allowed me to use certain options like "combine javascript output into a file" and so on.

I then upgraded to VS 2019 Community as well, and cannot find the "Typescript Build" equivalent for the life of me.

Can anyone point in the right direction as to where this is currently placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I gave up and went to VS Code, where all the love for Typescript seems to be nowadays. Not really an answer, but it seems if you wish to have specialized build options, go through the route of directly (and manually) configuring the associated `tsconfig.json` file